# Touch-based scrolling not works in my JavaScript app, but in Linux File manager works perfectly

Tags: javascript, linux, electron, vertical-scrolling, touches

**I have trouble with touch-based scrolling in my app.
But when I try touch-based scrolling in linux file manager or notapad it works perfectly.**

I develop app in OS Linux Mint 20.04., kernel 5.4.0
The app is writtten i Javascript.
Node v19.8.1
electron 12.0:0

To control app I use touch screen - 3M (MT7.14.4 driver)

Is there a way how to make works touch-based scrolling in my app?
I think it has to be when I see scrolling in File manager.

I have tried already some CSS settings like:
**touch-action: auto
pointer-events: auto
-webkit-touch-callout: default;
-webkit-user-select: none;**

I have also tried to put:** export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1**
to **.bashrc**

Will be greatful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).